# RegEx "^" and "$" not working with Dreamweaver CS4

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I notice that Dreamweaver doesn't find targets at the beginning or end of a line, using the RegExp ^ and $ symbols. It's as if Dreamweaver puts their own characters at the beginning and end, so searching with "^function" doesn't find:

```
function getValue()
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you searching somewhere inside dreamweaver? They may not have implemented those anchors.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking inside a JavaScript file. But I didn't think the RegEx engine depended on the source having ^ and $ and the ends. It's job is to recognize when things are at the ends.

Comment: Regarding the request to close the question because it's not about "programming," Dreamweaver is an IDE so no questions about it are going to be about programming; they're going to be about the user interface. If you don't want questions like that you shouldn't have a Dreamweaver tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html

> To make ^ and $ match the beginning or end of a line, you must
>   **precede the regex with (?m)**. However, the text must use only a line feed character. You need to remove carriage returns from text
>   created on Windows, and replace Mac carriage returns with line feeds.
>   The parentheses of (?m) are not counted as a capturing group.

Comment: That was a great reference, but the section you referenced seems to be in regard to Cold Fusion. Entering (?m)^function as a RegEx in Dreamweaver gives the error: "invalid quantifier."